# SharePoint 2010 On-Premise vs On-Line deployment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

If our team has to decide between On-Premise or On-Line deployment for SharePoint 2010 what all main factors we have to keep in mind before final decision?

What will be top 5 factors priority wise?

Answer (score 1):

It depends really on what your business requires. If you need to deploy custom code you will need an on-premises deployment. If you need to access LOB data, you will need an on-premises deployment. If you want control over Service Applications (such as Search crawling intervals, etc), you will need an on-premises deployment.